# TapGestureRecognizer calling function in another class and access variables of first class

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am calling a function in another class, as soon as I tap onto an UIImageView in my first ViewController:

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: secondclass, action: #selector(secondclass.imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
```

In my secondclass I need to access some variables from my first ViewController.

How can I get a reference to my first ViewController to achieve this?

secondclass:

```
@objc func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{

    let tappedImage = tapGestureRecognizer.view as! UIImageView

    //reference to first ViewController needed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then add a delegate inside the SecondVC

```
weak var delegate:FirstVC?
```

And configure it inside the first vc like

```
secondclass.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with delegate between ViewControllers.

```
protocol ImageDelegate: class {
    func didTapped()
}

class FirstVC: UIViewController, ImageDelegate {
    let imageView: UIImageView!
    let secondVC: SecondVC!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        secondVC.imageDelegate = self

    }


}
class SecondVC: UIViewController {
    weak var imageDelegate: ImageDelegate? 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
    }

    @objc func handleTap() {
        imageDelegate?.didTapped()
    } 
}
```